# How to connect MySQL Server and Apache Server

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mysql, webserver

I have installed two Linux (Fedora 12) systems. One running Apache server or one running MySQL Server.

I want to make a connection with each other to run my web server. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know how that stuff works in principle? You don't connect Apache with a MySQL server *per se*. Web applications that for example run in PHP need a MySQL connection defined, but Apache doesn't even need to know that you have a MySQL server. Your question isn't clear — what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am stablish a LAMP Web Server in my LAN. I am installed two Linux(Fedora) PC. I want that my one server allow for (Mysql) running as mysql Server for sql file and one for server run as a Apache server for core base.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to be more clear. I don't understand. What applications do you want to run on that Apache web server? What would you need the SQL database for?

Comment: I have two server first server ip (10.0.0.12) or second server ip (10.0.0.25) on first server i want to run apache server such as running lms such as (10.0.0.12/lms) or i want my lms sql file should run from second server (10.0.0.25) I have install all LAMP services and it is running perfectly but i am unable to connect mysql from second system. core should be run from first server and sql file access from second server. guide my step my step.

Comment: Select a language for example PHP.  When you write the PHP specify the IP address of the database server.
$dbhandle = mysql_connect('10.0.0.25', $_SESSION["username"], $_SESSION["password"])

Answer (score 1):

In your MySQL Config, make sure that you change the binding from localhost to nothing or the Apache server.

You will see a line in `/etc/mysql/my.ini` (if that is where it installed to) called `bind 127.0.0.1`. Either comment out that line and restart the mysql service or put in the IP address of your apache box.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you'll get more help if you:

- Ask a specific question
- Show us what you've already tried

Here's a link to the [PHP manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) that describe how to connect to a MySQL instance from a PHP page.  Read through it, and check out the examples  Figure out which port MySQL is listening on (default is 3306, I think) and make sure that's open on your MySQL server.

Give that a shot and if you still have questions about this particular task, StackOverflow is probably a better place to ask it.

Comment: I have two server first server ip (10.0.0.12) or second server ip (10.0.0.25) on first server i want to run apache server such as running lms such as (10.0.0.12/lms) or i want my lms sql file should run from second server (10.0.0.25) I have install all LAMP services and it is running perfectly but i am unable to connect mysql from second system. core should be run from first server and sql file access from second server. i don,t have knowledge about iptables guide me step my step.

Comment: Just follow the directions in the PHP manual pages.